# JSON implementation in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I am a beginner in JSON JQuery Languages. i want to implement the Following API to retrieve the currency rates in my html code. Anyone Help? i am working Since Last Week on this project but nothing happens.

The API is: http://ravi.coeus-solutions.de/api/v1/rates/list?user_auth=NDYyZjAxMzg3ODhlNDc1ZDA4NTY2ZWNkYmNmYjdiMDE4OGE3MjBkMGUwODlmMWM3OGVjNWRlNGM3Mzc0OWEzMg

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post EFFORT and CODE. Also your link is marked "Suspicious" by my firewall. Also do not post your AUTH code here. If they do not implement CORS you cannot use their code in your page without passing it through a server proxy

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you can start reading about `$.getJSON` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score -1):

You need to call object from json:

Go to following link for reference:
[JSON HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_html.asp)

Use  `JSON.parse(obj)` function.

Comment: The question is from beginner. and W3school is best for beginners. I never give whole solution if we give whole solution then how they will learn new things. That's why i given a link that questioner will go through that and learn.

Comment: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/why-shouldnt-i-use-w3schools-as-reference